# Azure debug with IIS express & VS2010 won't work anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, iis-express

I have a project with uses IIS Express as local development server but when starting a project with CTRL+F5 IIS express won't start anymore. I can't see IIS Express icon on taskbar. If I start without debugging, the project will start without problems and I can see  the icon on the taskbar.

From %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\dftmp\IISConfiguratorLogs\IISConfigurator.log file I see it's some kind of timeout error:

```
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00007792:00000005, 2012/08/15 20:13:59.67] IIS Express failed to start app pool 'xxxx' within the expected timeout
```

I have also tried to set full IIS as development server for this project, but I get the below error message. With my other Azure project, I have set full IIS as development server and it works fine.

```
There was an error attaching the debugger for the IIS worker process for URL 'xxxx' for role instance 'xxxx'. Unable to start debugging on the web server. See help for common configuration errors. Running the web page outside of the debugger may provide further information.
```

My co-workers can debug this project without any problems. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Got it actually working by installing VS 2012.